# What are the advantages of using parcelable?

Tags: java, android

Is it any different that we refer to a class object that doesn't use parcelable?

When we value a Parcel, we have to make an object of that class.
The same is true when reading it.

If we are actually referring to a class object when reading and writing, what difference does it make to using  Parcelable that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it takes a little effort to make a custom class implement `Parcelable`, the reward is that one can easily pass them as extras to a `Bundle`. A `Bundle` is a data container used for communication between various components in the Android universe, see also this guide on [Parcelables and Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles).

Consider the case where you want to pass an instance of a custom class from an `Activity` to a `Fragment`. A `Fragment` has an *arguments* `Bundle` which is customarily used for initializing the `Fragment`. (I suppose because the `Bundle` will still accessible if the user navigates away from the app and the whole app is stopped and restored from the back stack an hour later. On the other hand, any values passed in via the constructor will be lost if the `Fragment` did not save them in yet another `Bundle` in `onSaveInstanceState()`)

So it's good if a value can be stored in an `Bundle`. Objects belonging to classes which  implement `Parcelable` are of this type, together with primitive data types, some arrays, lists and serializable objects.

It's even more convenient if the value can be retrieved without having to do a class cast, that's why I prefer `Parcelable` over `Serializable` whenever possible:

Suppose we have two classes which implement `Serializable` respectively `Parcelable`. 
And suppose we have a `Bundle b = getArguments();`

To retrieve the `Serializable` value, you need the following statement

```
SomeSerializableClass instanceOfSerializableClass = (SomeSerializableClass)b.getSerializable("keyForSerializableValue");
```

whereas for the `Parcelable` value you can write

```
SomeParcelableClass instanceOfParcelableClass = b.getParcelable("keyForParcelableValue");
```

In Kotlin we have one of the rare cases where the statement is longer than its Java counterpart:

```
val instanceOfSerializableClass: SomeSerializableClass? = b.getSerializable("keyForSerializableValue") as SomeSerializableClass
```

compared to

```
val instanceOfParcelableClass = b.getParcelable<SomeParcelableClass>("keyForParcelableValue");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...its useful.